# How is sweetness measured?

Tags: perception, measurement

Some time ago, I read in a newspaper--though I can't recall the details--a list of (mostly artificial) sweeteners and a list comparing how many times sweeter each was than sugar. How is relative sweetness quantified? Is there a standard method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response of the gustatory receptor neurons can be measured using standard electrophysiological techniques, under different conditions(exposure to substances). For example see [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/neu.20063/full) article.

However, it is difficult to say if a person feels sweetness or not or how the substance produces complex taste perceptions in some people.

Comment: What I had read was the they had even measured the sweetness of something which was toxic (see the question's edit history). How could they have done that? Making a human have toxic material?

Comment: Please mention the source of this information. Toxic can also mean potentially toxic over continued use. They could have tested this in mice. To say anything we need to investigate the real source. Relying on newspapers for scientific facts is sometimes like playing chinese whispers. The reporters hear something, understand half. Add some of their interpretation and end up reporting erroneous information.

Comment: Hard to tell the source of it. Just remember reading and being amazed by the fact.